# Could this javascript date function fail?

Tags: javascript, date

Keeping in mind DST, Leaps, Timezones.

Can this function ever screw things up?  It must take a unix epoch (GMT) and figure out the exact calendar day of that epoch and return the epoch at 12:00AM of that day.

```
function convertToDayStartTime(epoch) {
  var d = new Date(0);
  d.setUTCSeconds(epoch);
  var dayStart = new Date(d.toDateString()).getTime()/1000;
  return dayStart;
}
```

For example:

```
expect(convertToDayStartTime(1378000800)).toEqual(1377993600);
```

EDIT:

Looks like it is a bit screwed up.  Following test fails:

```
expect(convertToDayStartTime(1377993599)).toEqual(1377907200);
```

I am not sure how to fix.

Comment: Is it `12:00 AM` local time or GMT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks to me like it will be exactly as correct as your browser's implementation of `Date`. However, I think you can simplify it: you know how long a day is -- 86400 seconds. So just find the nearest multiple of 86400 and go with that. You could implement it like this:

```
function convertToDayStartTime(epoch) {
    return Math.floor(epoch / 86400) * 86400;
}
```

Which gives 1377907200 for your example, as expected.

Comment: I guess that probably would be the best... i was thinking in terms of DST, etc... but I guess even with all the DST and leaping in the world, it couldn't possibly result in being over 86400/2 off the epoch time.  So your solution is probably the best...  (By the way I am in node not browser)

Comment: Leap seconds are not a problem, because the UNIX timestamp doesn't consider that. However, you must not assume all days last 86400 seconds...